# При ообновлении данных из mysql не работает верификация (обновление данных в CRUD)

Tags: php, mysql

У меня вопрос. Цель данной страницы заключается в том чтобы ввести номер студента, найти данный номер в базе данных и если номер сучествует то все данные данного студента появляются в форме где их можно изменить. Все работает, при вводе номера появляется форма со всеми данными, их можно изменить и все при нажатии обновляается. 
Цель в том чтобы при вводе новых данный проводилась их верификация и если все проходит то выскакивает соответствуюшее сообшение, если не проходит то появляется сообшение с ошибками и опять же форма. Код для етого есть и он полностью работает на страницe добавнения нового студента, а вот на странице обновления неработает, возможно я его нетуда вставляю.Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно исправить.

Вот код из mysql_connection отвечаюший за апдейт:

```
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'students_crud');

//connection

$db_connection = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR
die("Could not connect to MySQL! ". mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset($db_connection, 'utf8');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $sNum = $_POST['sNum'];
    $fName = $_POST['fName'];
    $lName = $_POST['lName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $add1 = $_POST['add1'];
    $add2 = $_POST['add2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $eircode = $_POST['eir'];
    $hNum = $_POST['hNum'];
    $mNum = $_POST['mNum'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $major = $_POST['major'];
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $sMode = $_POST['sMode'];
    $start_date = $_POST['start'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end'];


    mysqli_query($db_connection, "UPDATE student SET student_no = '$sNum', first_name = '$fName', last_name = '$lName', email = '$email', date_of_birth = '$dob',
     gender = '$gender', mobile = '$mNum', home_tel = '$hNum', add1 = '$add1',add2 = '$add2',city = '$city',state = '$state',eir = '$eircode', major = '$major', course = '$course',
      study_mode = '$sMode', start_date = '$start_date', end_date = '$end_date' WHERE student_no = '$sNum'");
}
```

А вот полный код из файла update_Student.php:

```
<?php include('mysql_connect.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29f1e2c7c5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Student's details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main_wrap">
    <div class="try">
        <div class="container upd_container">
            <div id='student_expanded_wrap_header'>
                <h2>Enter student's number to update:</h2>
            </div>
            <a href="student_management_system.php"><button type="button" name="back" class="btn mybtn btn-primary ch"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Back to main page</button></a>
            <form id="upd_form" class="get_data" action="update_student.php" method="get">
                <div class="row no-gutters mt-3 align-items-center search-wrap">
                    <div class="col search-bar">
                        <input class="form-control pr-5" type="search" name="search_student" placeholder="Search by student number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <button type="submit" name="sub" class="btn search-btn text-dark border-0 ml-n5">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <?php

        if(isset($_GET['search_student'])){
            $search = $_GET['search_student'];
//    $sNum = $_GET['search_student'];
            $trimmedSearch = trim($search);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_no = '$trimmedSearch'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    if (!isset($_POST['update'])) {
                        // Retrieve individual field value
                        $sNum = $row["student_no"];
                        $fName = $row['first_name'];
                        $lName = $row['last_name'];
                        $email = $row['email'];
                        $add1 = $row['add1'];
                        $add2 = $row['add2'];
                        $city = $row['city'];
                        $state = $row['state'];
                        $eircode = $row['eir'];
                        $hNum = $row['home_tel'];
                        $mNum = $row['mobile'];
                        $dob = $row['date_of_birth'];
                        $gender = $row['gender'];
                        $major = $row['major'];
                        $course = $row['course'];
                        $sMode = $row['study_mode'];
                        $start_date = $row['start_date'];
                        $end_date = $row['end_date'];

                        echo "    <form action=\"update_student.php\" method=\"post\" class=\"jumbotron\">
            <div class=\"col\">
                <input hidden type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"sNum\" value='$sNum'  placeholder=\"Student number\" required maxlength=\"7\">
            </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"col\">
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"fName\" value='$fName' placeholder=\"First name\" pattern=\"[A-Za-z]{1,32}\"
                       required>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"lName\" value='$lName'  placeholder=\"Last name\" pattern=\"[A-Za-z]{1,32}\"
                       required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class=\"form-group\">
            <label for=\"inputEmail\">Email</label>
            <input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputEmail\" name=\"email\" value='$email' placeholder=\"myemail@email.com\">
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-group\">
            <label for=\"inputAddress\">Address</label>
            <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"add1\" value='$add1' id=\"inputAddress\" placeholder=\"1234 Main St\" required>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-group\">
            <label for=\"inputAddress2\">Address 2</label>
            <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"add2\" value='$add2' id=\"inputAddress2\"
                   placeholder=\"Apartment, studio, or floor\" required>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputCity\">City</label>
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"city\" value='$city' id=\"inputCity\" placeholder=\"eg. Dublin\"
                       pattern=\"^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$\" required maxlength=\"20\">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-4\">
                <label for=\"inputState\">State</label>
                <select name=\"state\" id=\"inputState\" value='$state' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option value=\"Co.Dublin\">Co.Dublin</option>
                    <option value=\"Other\">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-2\">
                <label for=\"inputEirCode\">Eircode</label>
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" value='$eircode' id=\"inputEirCode\" name=\"eir\">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputHomeNum\">Home number</label>
                <input type=\"number\" name=\"hNum\" value='$hNum' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputHomeNum\" placeholder=\"eg. 011234567\"
                       pattern=\"[01][0-9]{7}\" maxlength=\"9\">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputMobileNum\">Mobile number</label>
                <input type=\"number\" name=\"mNum\" value='$mNum' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputMobileNum\" placeholder=\"eg. 087243525\"
                       pattern=\"[0-9]{3}[0-9]{7}\" required maxlength=\"10\">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputDOB\">Date of birth</label>
                <input type=\"date\" name=\"dob\" value='$dob' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputDOB\" required>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6 gen\">            
                <label for=\"inputGender\">Gender</label>
                <select id=\"inputGender\" name=\"gender\" value='$gender' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputMajor\">Major</label>
                <select id=\"inputMajor\" name=\"major\" value='$major' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>Computer Science</option>
                    <option>Business</option>
                    <option>Engineering</option>
                    <option>Psychology</option>
                    <option>Journalism</option>
                    <option>Arts</option>
                    <option>Mathematics</option>
                    <option>Philosophy</option>
                    <option>Architecture</option>
                    <option>Biology</option>
                    <option>Fitness studies</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputCourse\">Course</label>
                <select id=\"inputCourse\" name=\"course\" value='$course' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>BSCH</option>
                    <option>BSC</option>
                    <option>BS</option>
                    <option>BA</option>
                    <option>MSC</option>
                    <option>PhD</option>
                    <option>MA</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"col\">
                <label for=\"inputStudyMode\">Study mode</label>
                <select id=\"inputStudyMode\" name=\"sMode\" value='$sMode' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>Full-time</option>
                    <option>Part-time</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <label for=\"inputStartDate\">Start date</label>
                <input type=\"date\" name=\"start\" value='$start_date' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputStartDate\" required>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <label for=\"inputEndDate\">End date</label>
                <input type=\"date\" name=\"end\" id=\"inputEndDate\" value='$end_date' class=\"form-control\" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class=\"btns\">
            <a id='view_details' href='update_student.php?sub=" . $row['student_no'] . "' ><button type=\"submit\" name=\"update\"  class=\"btn mybtn btn-primary\">Register Student</button></a>
            <a href=\"student_management_system.php\"><button type=\"button\" style='color:white;' name=\"back\" class=\"btn mybtn\"><i class=\"fas fa-home\"></i>Back to main page</button></a>
        </div>
    </form>";}
                    else {
                        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                            $errors = array();
                            $trimmedFName = trim($fName);
                            $trimmedLName = trim($lName);
                            $trimmedAdd1 = trim($add1);
                            $trimmedAdd2 = trim($add1);
                            $trimmedCity = trim($city);
                            $trimmedEircode = trim($eircode);
                            $trimmedHomeNum = trim($hNum);
                            $trimmedMobileNum = trim($mNum);
                            $trimmedEmail = trim($email);

                            if (empty($sNum)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Student number is required!';
                            } else {
                                $stNum = trim($_POST['sNum']);
                                $stNumLength = strlen($stNum);
                                if ($stNumLength > 7) {
                                    $errors[] = 'Invalid student number! Student number must be 7 characters long.';
                                }
                            }

                            if (empty($fName)) {
                                $errors[] = 'First name is required!';
                            } else if (!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]{1,32}/", $trimmedFName)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Invalid first name! First name must contain only capital and small letters.';
                            }

                            if (empty($lName)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Last name is required!';
                            } else if (!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]{1,32}/", $trimmedLName)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Invalid last name! Last name must contain only capital and small letters.';
                            }

                            if (empty($email)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Email is required.';
                            } else if (!filter_var($trimmedEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                $errors[] = "Invalid email address.";
                            }


                            if (empty($add1)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Address 1 is required!';
                            } else if (!preg_match('/^[#.0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $trimmedAdd1)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Invalid Address 1! Address 1 must only contain digits, spaces, upper and lowercase letters.';
                            } else {
                                $add1Length = strlen($trimmedAdd1);
                                if ($add1Length > 20) {
                                    $errors[] = 'Invalid address 1! Address 1 must not exceed 20 characters.';
                                }
                            }

                            if (empty($add2)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Address 2 is required!';
                            } else if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z ]+/", $trimmedAdd2)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Invalid Address 2! Address 2 must only contain digits, spaces, upper and lowercase letters.';
                            } else {
                                $add2Length = strlen($trimmedAdd2);
                                if ($add2Length > 20) {
                                    $errors[] = 'Invalid address 2! Address 2 must not exceed 20 characters.';
                                }
                            }

                            if (empty($trimmedCity)) {
                                $errors[] = "City is required!";
                            } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$/", $trimmedCity)) {
                                $errors[] = 'Invalid city name! City name must only contain upper and lower case letters.';
                            } else {
                                $cityLength = strlen($trimmedCity);
                                if ($cityLength > 20) {
                                    $errors[] = 'Invalid city name! City name must not exceed 20 characters.';
                                }
                            }

                            if (empty($eircode)) {
                                $errors[] = "Eircode is required!";
                            } else {
                                $eircodeLength = strlen($trimmedEircode);
                                if ($eircodeLength < 8 || $eircodeLength > 8) {
                                    $errors[] = "Invalid eircode! Eircode must only contain 7 characters and 1 space.";
                                }
                            }

                            if (empty($hNum)) {
                                $errors[] = "Home number is required!";
                            } else if (!preg_match("/[01][0-9]{7}/", $trimmedHomeNum)) {
                                $errors[] = "Invalid home number! Home number must only contain digits and should be 7 digits long";
                            } else {
                                $hNumLength = strlen($trimmedHomeNum);
                                if ($hNumLength > 9) {
                                    $errors[] = "Invalid home number! Home number must not exceed 7 digits.";
                                }
                            }

                            if (empty($mNum)) {
                                $errors[] = "Mobile number is required!";
                            } else if (!preg_match("/[08][0-9]{7}/", $trimmedMobileNum)) {
                                $errors[] = "Invalid mobile number! Mobile number must only contain digits and should be 7 digits long";
                            } else {
                                $mNumLength = strlen($trimmedMobileNum);
                                if ($mNumLength > 10) {
                                    $errors[] = "Invalid mobile number! Mobile number must not exceed 10 digits.";
                                }
                            }


                            if (empty($errors)) {
                                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\"><h4>Student successfully added!</h4></div>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"><h4>Error! The following error(s) occured:</h4>";
                                foreach ($errors as $msg) {
                                    echo "<h5>- $msg </h5>";
                                }
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "    <form action=\"add_student.php\" method=\"post\" class=\"jumbotron\">
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"col\">
                <input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"sNum\" value='$sNum'  placeholder=\"Student number\" required maxlength=\"7\">
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"fName\" value='$fName' placeholder=\"First name\" pattern=\"[A-Za-z]{1,32}\"
                       required>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"lName\" value='$lName'  placeholder=\"Last name\" pattern=\"[A-Za-z]{1,32}\"
                       required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class=\"form-group\">
            <label for=\"inputEmail\">Email</label>
            <input type=\"email\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputEmail\" name='$email' placeholder=\"myemail@email.com\">
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-group\">
            <label for=\"inputAddress\">Address</label>
            <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"add1\" value='$add1' id=\"inputAddress\" placeholder=\"1234 Main St\" required>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-group\">
            <label for=\"inputAddress2\">Address 2</label>
            <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"add2\" value='$add2' id=\"inputAddress2\"
                   placeholder=\"Apartment, studio, or floor\" required>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputCity\">City</label>
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"city\" value='$city' id=\"inputCity\" placeholder=\"eg. Dublin\"
                       pattern=\"^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$\" required maxlength=\"20\">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-4\">
                <label for=\"inputState\">State</label>
                <select name=\"state\" id=\"inputState\" value='$state' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option value=\"Co.Dublin\">Co.Dublin</option>
                    <option value=\"Other\">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-2\">
                <label for=\"inputEirCode\">Eircode</label>
                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" value='$eircode' id=\"inputEirCode\" name=\"eir\">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputHomeNum\">Home number</label>
                <input type=\"number\" name=\"hNum\" value='$hNum' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputHomeNum\" placeholder=\"eg. 011234567\"
                       pattern=\"[01][0-9]{7}\" maxlength=\"9\">
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputMobileNum\">Mobile number</label>
                <input type=\"number\" name=\"mNum\" value='$mNum' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputMobileNum\" placeholder=\"eg. 087243525\"
                       pattern=\"[0-9]{3}[0-9]{7}\" required maxlength=\"10\">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputDOB\">Date of birth</label>
                <input type=\"date\" name=\"dob\" value='$dob' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputDOB\" required>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6 gen\">            
                <label for=\"inputGender\">Gender</label>
                <select id=\"inputGender\" name=\"gender\" value='$gender' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputMajor\">Major</label>
                <select id=\"inputMajor\" name=\"major\" value='$major' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>Computer Science</option>
                    <option>Business</option>
                    <option>Engineering</option>
                    <option>Psychology</option>
                    <option>Journalism</option>
                    <option>Arts</option>
                    <option>Mathematics</option>
                    <option>Philosophy</option>
                    <option>Architecture</option>
                    <option>Biology</option>
                    <option>Fitness studies</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=\"form-group col-md-6\">
                <label for=\"inputCourse\">Course</label>
                <select id=\"inputCourse\" name=\"course\" value='$course' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>BSCH</option>
                    <option>BSC</option>
                    <option>BS</option>
                    <option>BA</option>
                    <option>MSC</option>
                    <option>PhD</option>
                    <option>MA</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"form-row\">
            <div class=\"col\">
                <label for=\"inputStudyMode\">Study mode</label>
                <select id=\"inputStudyMode\" name=\"sMode\" value='$sMode' class=\"form-control\" required>
                    <option selected>Full-time</option>
                    <option>Part-time</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <label for=\"inputStartDate\">Start date</label>
                <input type=\"date\" name=\"start\" value='$start_date' class=\"form-control\" id=\"inputStartDate\" required>
            </div>
            <div class=\"col\">
                <label for=\"inputEndDate\">End date</label>
                <input type=\"date\" name=\"end\" id=\"inputEndDate\" value='$end_date' class=\"form-control\" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class=\"btns\">
            <button type=\"submit\" name=\"update\"  class=\"btn mybtn btn-primary\">Register Student</button>
            <a href=\"student_management_system.php\"><button type=\"button\" name=\"back\" class=\"btn mybtn\"><i class=\"fas fa-home\"></i>Back to main page</button></a>
        </div>
    </form>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                ?>
                <?php
            } else {?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">Student doesn't exist!</div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Руки конечно надо отрывать тем преподавателям, которые учат студентов такому кошмару...

Comment: Что есть то есть...

Comment: Не думаю что большинство будут пытаться прочитать и понять ваш код. Рекомендую прочитать правила создания вопроса в Справке внизу и отредактировать вопрос так, чтобы он отражал суть вашей проблемы. Так, глядишь, в процессе урезания, вы и сами начнёте понимать что может быть источником проблемы. Читать всю простыню - это на любителя, тем более возиться с нею и выяснять что же именно с ней не так. Опять же рекомендую ознакомиться с основами отладки, которая в будущем вам поможет (и не один раз).